# Laravel Eloquent: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am building a website where many members can join many groups.

```
//User.php
public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class, 'group_member', 'member_id', 'group_id');
    }
```

The function to retrieve related members from the group id

```
//UserRepository.php
public function getRelatedMembersByGroupIds(array $groupIds)
    {
        $members = User::whereHas('groups', function ($query) use ($groupIds) {
            return $query->whereIn('groups.id', $groupIds);
        });
        return $members->get();
    }
```

The repository is being called from the UserController

```
//UserController.php
public function getRelatedMembersByGroupIds(Request $request)
    {
        $groupIds = $request->get('group_ids');

        $members = $this->userRepository->getRelatedMembersByGroupIds($groupIds);

        $responses = [
            'status' => 'success',
            'groupRelatedMembers' => $members
        ];

        return response()->json($responses);
    }
```

It returns

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in
>   where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select users.* from users where exists
>   (select * from groups inner join group_member on groups.id =
>   group_member.group_id where users.id = group_member.member_id and
>   groups.id in (1) and groups.deleted_at is null and id = 1))

Comment: Hint: `and id = 1`

Comment: you are missing some part of the code, there is where('id', 1) some where

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: 1 is group_id from the request.

Comment: Yes my bad, 1 was not coming from the group_id. It came from the global scope I implemented in the GroupScope.php

Comment: `whereIn('groups.id', $groupIds)` is usually not necessary, `whereIn('id', $groupIds)` should work and might allow creation of table aliases (not 100% sure on this though)

Comment: @apokryfos It seem to display error of Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous when I use ```whereIn('id')```. Probably because it was joining Groups and Members table at the same time.

Comment: This should normally work though. The `WHERE EXISTS` part is what `whereHas` generates which checks that related models exist for the current user (whose `id = 1` I'm assuming which is why that's there) What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel Version 5.7.28

Comment: Is there any scope in effect that would add that `id=1` in the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I forgot I had implemented a global scope for Group model. After adding groups.id in the GroupScope, It worked fine.

```
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use App\Helpers\AuthenticationHelper;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class GroupScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        if (AuthenticationHelper::isEmployee())
        {
            //Problem was I did not added groups table below.
            $builder->where('groups.id', auth()->user()->branch_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to delete this useless question, then

Comment: Was about to delete and got "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it."

Comment: Then all is well :-)

Comment: I had the same issue, caused by the exact mistake, so thanks for posting this answer to your own question.

Answer (score 9):

In last where clause, there is "**id=1**". You need to express it as "**table_name**.id=1".

Comment: hey dude that's not the issue

Comment: it says  ambiguous because the users table an the group table has the id column

Answer (score 5):

i am not daam sure but it may work

Your Code

```
public function getRelatedMembersByGroupIds(array $groupIds)
    {
        $members = User::whereHas('groups', function ($query) use ($groupIds) {
            return $query->whereIn('groups.id', $groupIds);
        });
        return $members->get();
    }
```

Can You `dd($members)` and share the result so i will dig deep into the issue

Comment: Thank you. id = 1 was from the auth()->user()->branch_id I implemented on the GroupScope.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it was due to multi-tenant `TenantScope` scope.

The fix was to prefix the field with the table name - which was generic in my case - as the scope is applied to all models.

My solution was to use `$model->getTable()` as below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use App\Helpers\AuthenticationHelper;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class GroupScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        if (AuthenticationHelper::isEmployee())
        {
            //Problem was I did not added groups table below.
            $builder->where($model->getTable() . '.id', auth()->user()->branch_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just want to say thanks, I was stuck in the same problem from many days. you help solve it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with the multi-tenant scope this change works for me.

change from this

```
$builder->where('tenant_id', session()->get('tenant_id'));
```

to this

```
$builder->where($model->getTable() . '.tenant_id', session()->get('tenant_id'));



<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class TenantScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    use Notifiable;

    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        if (session()->has('tenant_id')) {
            $builder->where($model->getTable() . '.tenant_id', session()->get('tenant_id'));
        }
    }
}
```

thank you all so much.